# Test is not executed when pytest.fixture is used

Tags: python, pytest

I have a simple Python library, for which I use the following command to run tests:

`python setup.py pytest`

The following test works as expected:

```
def test_out():
    assert 1 == 2
```

Test result:

```
platform linux -- Python 3.10.4, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /media/drive2/src
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                           

tests/test_error.py F
```

---

However, when `@pytest.fixture` is added, the test is not executed:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture

def test_out():
    assert 1 == 2
```

Test result:

```
platform linux -- Python 3.10.4, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /media/drive2/src
collected 0 items
```

---

What is the reason for this behavior, and how can `@pytest.fixture` be added in a way that won't prevent the test from running?

(I want to use `capsys.readouterr()`, so I believe `@pytest.fixture` is needed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `pytest.fixture` is a decorator, so it is affecting the function below, and the right way to use it is to put them together (no empty lines in between), like this:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def test_out():
    assert 1 == 2   # This still makes no sense, see answer below
```

`@pytest.fixture` just indicates that the return value of the decorated function will be use as parameter in other test function. (The decorated function will not run as a test).

From the [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CFixtures%E2%80%9D%2C%20in%20the%20literal%20sense%2C%20are%20each%20of%20the%20arrange%20steps%20and%20data.%20They%E2%80%99re%20everything%20that%20test%20needs%20to%20do%20its%20thing.):

> “Fixtures”, in the literal sense, are each of the arrange steps and data. They’re everything that test needs to do its thing.

Here is an example similar to your test using a fixture:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def my_number():
    return 2

def test_out(my_number):
    assert 1 == my_number  # This will fail
```

When you create the fixture `my_number` the retorned value can be use as parameter in other test functions (in this case in `test_out`).

This is usefull when you have to create the same stuff in several tests. Instead of repeating the code in each test you can make a fixture.